# Myeclipse: when make change in Design View, automatically change to Source View

Tags: swing, myeclipse, matisse

I'm using MyEclipse and use Matisse to programming Swing.

This function of MyEclipse has one thing make me annoy: when you change something in design view (add component, resize, add event,... anythings), MyEclipse will automatically generated code and change from Design to Code View.

So, each time I change something, I must click on design View Tab again. (You can imagine that a button has some properties, such as: method on mouse click, mouse over, text on this button, size of it,....), each property, I must choose View tab again...

Please help me fix this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this on the MyEclipse forums and, if you have MyEclipse for Spring, then there may be a solution here: http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=130152#130152

If you're not using MyEclipse for Spring then you might consider switching to the Swing Designer for MyEclipse, that can be added through the MyEclipse Configuration Center dashboard. That seems to be the recommended route now and probably a better option if you can move away from Matisse, since the Swing Designer doesn't need a separate form file (it operates just from the Java source).